# Отрисовка нескольких элементов tablist в Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Всем привет.
В настоящий момент имею следующий код (на основе https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/):

```
<div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#list_1" role="tab" aria-controls="list_1" aria-selected="true">Один</a>
    <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#list_2" role="tab" aria-controls="list_2" aria-selected="false">Два</a>
    <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#list_3" role="tab" aria-controls="list_3" aria-selected="false">Три</a>
</div>
<div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent" id="CheckBoxRole">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="list_1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">
        Отрисовка по функции с параметром 1
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list_2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">
        Отрисовка по функции с параметром 2
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list_3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">
        Отрисовка по функции с параметром 3
    </div>
</div>
```

Появилась необходимость на этой же странице (но в другом месте) отображать дополнительные блоки, по нажатию на один из элементов nav-link.
Т.е. к примеру при нажатии на "Один" помимо

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="list_2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">
    Отрисовка по функции с параметром 2
</div>
```

дополнительно отобразить

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="list_2_right" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">
    Отрисовка по доп. функции с параметром 2
</div>
```

и т.д.

Кто может подсказать решение (или альтернативный способ, желательно без использования collapse)?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: а вы в `href` через запятую пробовали их прописать?

Comment: @teran не работает.

Comment: ничто вам не мешает в целом добавить обычный обработчик клика на ссылку-таб и показывать/скрывать там все что хотите или еще чего